# Python variable value not being added

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I am creating a simple game where you roll a die and move some random number of spaces. when i was doing this, the variable "position"'s value changes, but when it reaches 30 the  program still continues. Any solutions?

```
again = True
position = 1
while again:
    move_numb = 0
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll = input("> ")
    if roll == "roll":
        print("you moved " + str(number) + " spaces")
        position += number
        print("You are currently on " + "tile " + str(position))
        move_numb += 1
        **if position == 30:
            print("You Win")
            print("You reached here in " + str(move_numb) + " moves")
            break
        else:
            continue**
```

Comment: You're adding a random number onto `position`, but you're only checking if you hit 30 dead on, not if you went past it. Presumably `if position >= 30:`

Comment: `if position >= 30:`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to verify if you don't go further than 30 by doing `if position >= 30`

Use this code :

```
again = True
position = 1
move_numb = 0

while again:
    number = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll = input("> ")

    if roll == "roll":
        print("you moved " + str(number) + " spaces")
        position += number
        print("You are currently on " + "tile " + str(position))
        move_numb += 1

        if position >= 30:
          print("You Win")
          print("You reached here in " + str(move_numb) + " moves")
          again = False
```

Comment: But i come up with another problem. The number of moves always remains as 1

Comment: It's because you were reinitializing it in your `while loop`

Comment: That's why, you can see in my answer, i initialized the variable `move_numb` out of the while scope

Answer (score 0):

first of all is your idea to stop exactly when the tile is 30 or the tile crosses 30
if it is exactly 30 then your code is working well

if it is tile number >30 then a small change in your code should be

```
position>=30
```